# Differential Clocking resistor and capacitor choices

Tags: clock, differential

I am working on generating a 2MHz differential clock signal for a DDS chip. I have been given a PCB with a design that I am unsure can work or what the thought was behind it. If anyone could help with what I think is happening and what should/shouldn't be there. X01 is SI510. The CLK1_P is driving an AD9106. The board is four layers with the two inner layers being two power planes and a ground pour on top and bottom. (I think the top inner layer should be a ground plane)

1. R5 & R6 are pull-up and pull down resistors on the CLK- line. I do not think these are needed, I think they may be some kind of Thévenin termination, but I think the parallel termination is sufficient if done correctly.
2. R3 and R4 are a parallel termination to match the general characteristic impedance of ~100R. However only one should be needed and it should be as close to the pins as possible.
3. I do not know what C6 and R2 are doing.
4. R9, R10, C21 and C20 are forming low-pass filters (i think) to the AD9106. I think the capacitors should be 0.1uF and not 0.01uF, see the screenshot from the AD9106 datasheet below, and I am unsure of what the resistors, R9 and R10, to ground are doing if not used for low-pass fitlering.

I can clearly see a good 2MHz signal into the buffer, i.e. the clock setup is working somehow, but nothing is coming out of u3. Ideally i'd like to get this design working but implement any improvements.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which SI510 is in use? It comes in LVPECL, LVDS, and HCL differential flavors.  Also, what voltage is VCC_CLK?

Comment: Mc100ep11 is not an LVDS buffer, it is LVPECL. It may be producing a much stronger signal than the DAC is designed for.

Comment: The part number is 510AAA2M00000BAG and VCC_CLK is 3.3V